# Python: find smallest missing positive integer in ordered list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find the first missing number in a list. If there is no number missing, the next number should be the last +1.

It should first check to see if the first number is > 1, and if so then the new number should be 1.

Here is what I tried. The problem is here: `if next_value - items > 1:`
results in an error because at the end and in the beginning I have a `None`.

```
list = [1,2,5]
vlans3=list

for items in vlans3:
    if items in vlans3:

        index = vlans3.index(items)
        previous_value = vlans3[index-1] if index -1 > -1 else None
        next_value = vlans3[index+1] if index + 1 < len(vlans3) else None
        first = vlans3[0]
        last = vlans3[-1]

                #print ("index: ", index)
        print ("prev item:", previous_value)
        print ("-cur item:", items)
        print ("nxt item:", next_value)

        #print ("_free: ", _free)
        #print ("...")
        if next_value - items > 1:
            _free = previous_value + 1
            print ("free: ",_free)
            break

print ("**************")
print ("first item:", first)
print ("last item:", last)
print ("**************")
```

---

Another method:

```
L = vlans3

free = ([x + 1 for x, y in zip(L[:-1], L[1:]) if y - x > 1][0])
```

results in a correct number if there is a gap between the numbers, but if no space left error occurs: `IndexError: list index out of range`. However I need to specify somehow that if there is no free space it should give a new number (last +1). But with the below code it gives an error and I do not know why.

```
if free = []:
    print ("no free")
else:
    print ("free: ", free)
```

Comment: Can you be sure your original list only contains integers, and is it always in ascending order?

Comment: For your code instead of `if next_value - items > 1:` add this : `if next_value != None and next_value - items > 1 :` it will work

Comment: @CsabaDobo what do you mean by "It should first check to see if the first number is > 1, and if so then the new number should be 1"?

Answer (score 1):

To get the smallest integer that is not a member of `vlans3`:

```
ints_list = range(min(vlans3), max(vlans3) + 1)
missing_list = [x for x in ints_list if x not in vlans3]
first_missing = min(missing_list)
```

However you want to return 1 if the smallest value in your list is greater than 1, and the last value + 1 if there are no missing values, so this becomes:

```
ints_list = [1] + list(range(min(vlan3), max(vlan3) + 2))
missing_list = [x for x in ints_list if x not in vlan3]
first_missing = min(missing_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

First avoid using reserved word `list` for variable.
Second use try:except to quickly and neatly avoid this kind of issues.

```
def free(l):
    if l == []: return 0
    if l[0] > 1: return 1
    if l[-1] - l[0] + 1 == len(l): return l[-1] + 1
    for i in range(len(l)):
        try:
            if l[i+1] - l[i] > 1: break
        except IndexError:
            break
    return l[i] + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a `numpy` solution? Below code works if your input is a sorted integer list with non-duplicating positive values (or is empty).

*nekomatic*'s solution is a bit faster for small inputs, but it's just a fraction of a second, doesn't really matter. However, it does not work for large inputs - e.g. `list(range(1,100000))` completely freezes on list comprehension with inclusion check. Below code does not have this issue.

```python
import numpy as np

def first_free_id(array):
    array = np.concatenate((np.array([-1, 0], dtype=np.int), np.array(array, dtype=np.int)))
    where_sequence_breaks = np.where(np.diff(array) > 1)[0]
    return where_sequence_breaks[0] if len(where_sequence_breaks)>0 else array[-1]+1
```

1. Prepend the array with -1 and 0 so `np.diff` works for empty and 1-element lists without breaking existing sequence's continuity.
2. Compute differences between consecutive values. Seeked discontinuity ("hole") is where the difference is bigger than 1.
3. If there ary any "holes" return the id of the first one, otherwise return the integer succeeding the last element.